# Website moved from Win8 to Win2012 - SQLite query result went very slow

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, iis

I have a very strange problem I haven't figured out yet and need your help.

My development computer is a Win 8.1 Ent 64bit w. IIS and the server is a Win 2012 R2 Std. w. IIS.

On dev.comp. I also have VS 2013/IIS Express.

My website SQLite query results are at about 10-20 ms. on following setups:

- Win8 using Visual Studio 2013 / IIS Express

  - Both with and without being logged on w. Forms authentication
- Win8 using built-in IIS

  - Both with and without being logged on w. Forms authentication
- Win2012 using built-in IIS

  - Only when not logged on

BUT, as soon as I login at Win2012, the query results at about 1200-1500 ms.!!

Anyone knows what's going on here ???

**-----------Update-------------**

Now I have narrowed down the issue to the following:

I am using a class which make use of the IDataReader inferface and it's the IDBConnection object's "Open" method that increases in time from 10-20 ms to 1200-1500 ms when I am logged on to Win2012 and only then.

Have anyone ran into something similar before ?

Comment: Does it happen for every request? Or does it happen only for the first request?

Comment: @th1rdey3 It's consistent and happens every request, and If I logout from Win2012, the results becomes "normal" again at 10-20ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself ... I have had issues with this years ago, when I was using MS Access databases, where you sometimes had to set folder rights for the asp.net user ... and here we go again...

I had to add user rights for the "IIS AppPool" this time, to the folder where the SQLite database is, even if I'm only reading.

Thanks every one for listning ... sometimes it's enough :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! It saved me a lot of time.